Multicontainer deployment on Cloud Run
It looks like Google Cloud Run supports the sidecar pattern for multiple containers.
I wanted to deploy a front-end & backend containers on the same service on Cloud Run. I want to use the same local network to reduce latency. On a git push, a trigger would build both containers (this is easy) and finally update the Cloud Run service.
I'm reading the docs for the Cloud Run update and it seems that only 1 container/image can be updated? How do I update both containers of the service?
I'm looking for something like:
gcloud run services update service-name  --images (1) gcr.io/frontend:latest  (2) gcr.io/backend:latest
Is it possible to achieve on CloudRun? Or should I go with Autopilot / K8 cluster?

The commands for multicontainer are a bit complicated, because each container is more than just an image- it also can contain its own env vars, volume mounts, arguments, etc. So it's not just a matter of passing two image names. You have to name each container config and specify which one is exposing a port externally. The command should look something like this
gcloud run services update service-name --container frontend --image gcr.io/frontend --port 8080 --container backend --image gcr.io/backend
Documentation on this is here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#multicontainer-yaml

I’d recommend defining and referencing a service.yml as described in deploying service with sidecar using yaml - the yaml can be versioned in codebase and then referenced / deployed with:
gcloud run services replace service.yaml

Here is an example cloudrun service.yml from a similar frontend/ backend multi container deployment (a basic yaml like this is created in the cloudrun console under yaml section after first cloudrun setup/deployment):
Service.yml
spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      timeoutSeconds: 550
      serviceAccountName: xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      containers:
      - name: frontend-ui
        image: us.gcr.io/ai-prj/frontend:latest
        ports:
        - name: http1
          containerPort: 5173
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-conf-secret
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
        startupProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 240
          periodSeconds: 240
          failureThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5173
      - name: backend
        image: us.gcr.io/ai-prj/backend:latest
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: '8080'
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 4000m
            memory: 16Gi
        startupProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 120
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/monitoring/health
            port: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-conf-secret
        secret:
          secretName: nginx_config
          items:
          - key: latest
            path: default.conf

There is some nuance to running both frontend and backend within cloudrun, so I recommend reviewing Google's documentation on Frontend Proxying using NGINX and GitHub examples for multi container cloud run deployment.
